# (SQL) how to merge two columns together to create a new column and then join that table to another table which has that new column in common

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to merge two columns together (i.e. column_A & column_b and add '|' in between the columns) in  Table_1 which will form another column column_c. I then want to combine/join column_c from Table_1 with column_c from Table_2. The tables both have different columns in each respectively, and I want to return all of the data- only the column_c is the common column.

I've managed to merge the two columns by using

```
Select (column_a + '|' + column_b) as column_c from Table_1
```

But I am having trouble joining this with column_c from table_2.

So the query [select broker,account,trade_id,currency from transactions where trade_id = '45435'] will return the below:

broker  account trade_id    currency
HSBC    G-HG4_5 45435   EUR

and the query [select * from summary where code like 'G-HG4_5&'] will return

start_date  end_date    code                  description           broker type
25/05/2015  14/02/2015  G-HG4_5|EUR LONG           BARCLAYS

I basically want to combine the account & currency to make it look like the "code" column in the 2nd table. once combined, I want to put it all into one table where I can compare the data.

Comment: Hello Satish Patel, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide sample data for both tables and expected results, as tabular text. Data speaks louder than words.

Comment: Have you tried anything???  "I've managed to merge ..."  I don't see a query posted with this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your merge columns directly in JOIN by concatinating using + operator or Concat operator as shown below: Please try this:

```
SELECT t1.column_a, t2.column_b, t2.column_c -- add either * or columns list of your choice here
FROM TABLE_2 t2
INNER JOIN t1 ON  t2.column_c = (ISNULL(t1.column_a, '') + '|' + ISNULL(t1.column_b, '')) -- t2.column_c = concat(t1.column_a, '|', t1.column_b)
```

**Side Note:** If you use + to join then you will need to handle NULL value check explicitly as something like below will not execute:

```
SELECT null + '|' + 'fun';
SELECT 'fun' + '|' + null;
```

Comment: Can you please add an explanation to your solution!?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like what you are trying to do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_2 t2
INNER JOIN 
    (Select *, (column_a + '|' + column_b) as column_c from Table_1) t1
    ON t1.column_c = t2.column_c
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the concatenation in the join condition directly:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Table_1 a
INNER JOIN table_2 b
   ON CONCAT(a.column_a,'|',a.column_b)=b.column_c
```

Hope this helps.